# Difference between vex and annoy

Tags: meaning, differences

I learnt a new verb today, namely, *vex*. I read a lot of example sentences with it, and looked up the definitions. It seems that *vex* is very similar to *annoy*.

- Are there any contexts where one is applicable while the other is not?

If not,

- Are there any contexts where one is more preferable than the other?

Comment: Looking at the roots, "vex" comes from a word meaning "disturb"/"agitate", whereas "annoy" comes from "harm"/"tire"/"molest". Looks like "annoy" is a bit stronger--use it for more severe situations I guess.

Comment: In spoken English, 'vex' is unheard of, except for maybe by a very annoying older aunt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Vex* connotes being *frustrated* more than annoy does.  *Annoy* connotes being *bothered*.

I might be *annoyed* by a mosquito buzzing around my ear; I might be *vexed* by a difficult math problem.

*Vex* is also much better for [pangrams](http://able2know.org/topic/1941-1).

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your last sentence, could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Pangrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams) are sentences containing all the letters of the alphabet, like _The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog_.  The most interesting pangrams I've seen come from typeface examples.  My favorite is _Jelly-like above the high wire, six quaking pachyderms kept the climax of the extravaganza in a dazzling state of flux._

Comment: Well, I understand what a pangram is, I don't understand how *vex* is "much better" for it

Comment: My closing remark about pangrams was meant to be mildly amusing. Most pangram writers strive to use all the letters of the alphabet in as few characters as possible; that's the novelty of pangrams. Since _vex_ is only a 3-letter word, and two of those letters (x & v) are relatively little-used in English, _vex_ is a "valuable" pangram word. In fact, if you follow my original link, you'll see the word "vex" used 6 times, in a list of about 50 pangrams. It's a commonly-used pangram word - that's all. If my remark threw you off, I apologize; I didn't mean to vex you.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to @Manishearth's comment, I suggest on average [vexation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vexation) is stronger than [annoyance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annoyance). Definitions of *vexed* are likely to include *annoyed*, and vice-versa, but *distressed* is much more likely to only turn up with the former. It's also important to note the [long-term usage shift](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vexed%20me,annoyed%20me&year_start=1780&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

...which means that in modern parlance, using **vex** is at least a slightly unusual choice. Sometimes it's slightly self-conscious/facetious, sometimes it's in order to make a subtle distinction. As J.R. points out, by choosing *vex* you may be able to convey that you're being bothered by something you can't easily resolve (i.e. - it's truly frustrating), whereas oftentimes if something simply *annoys* you, you can just deal with it.

In general my advice to a non-native speaker would be to avoid *vex* in most contexts - you need to have a good "ear" for the way other people use it, otherwise your choice of vocabulary will just end up sounding quaint or dated, if not actually archaic.

Comment: Explanatory comment, please, downvoter?